# AngularJS open modal from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am new to angularjs, and writing an application where a template(inventory.html) containing grid is opened with , it has a  validate button at bottom of grid, which calls validate() to validate selected grid rows, before that i need a modal to popup and take user name as input and then process further.

my validate function is inside controller of template(i.e. inventory.html) .
I have a app.js which contains routing info and controller.js which contains controllers for all templates.

My question is, if there is any way that I can open modal from validate(), take user input and proceed further without writing separate controller for modal.
(I have a separate userinput.html for modal.)

(Sorry If my question is not clear. Plz help I am stuck with this and have tried many options from web)

// This is my controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('InventoryCtrl',['$scope','$location','$http','$modal',function($scope, $location, $http,$modal{console.log("Inside inventory ctrlr");

 // Validate Function for validate button click
 $scope.validate = function() 
    {   
        $scope.user = null;
        $scope.build = null;
        // Show modal to take user inputs for environment
        var modalInstance = $modal.open(
        {
            controller : "inputModalCntrl",
            templateUrl : "../partials/addEnvironment.html",
            resolve: {
                $callback: function () {
                    return function(param,user,build){
                        /* This function print value(param) dispached in modal controller */
                        console.log(param,user,build);
                                    $scope.user = user;
                                    $scope.build = build;
                    };
                },
                $send: function(){
                    return function(){
                        /* This function send param for the modal */
                        return {param1:"Hello Word Main"};
                    };
                }
            }
        });
// This is further process of function
     postdata = {};
     var dlist = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
        postdata['dlist'] = dlist;
     $http({ url: "/api/check",  data: postdata, method: "POST" })
    .success(function (response) { alert(response);})
    .error(function () { alert('Error getting data');});
 };
   }]);
```

and this is modal controller

```
app.controller("inputModalCntrl", function($scope, $modalInstance, $callback, $send) {
$scope.init = function(){
    /* This function print value(param) dispached in main controller */
    console.log($send);

    /* This send data to main controller */
    $callback({param1:"Hello Word Modal", user :user, build : build});
};
});
```

Comment: What you have tried up to now in coding?

Comment: Sorry, undestand your question. Try edit your post

Comment: @Sarjan Desai Example from [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) also tried putting controller in seperate file and the then involking them, setting controller as inline function.

Comment: @EmirMarques : I have a button which calls a function, inside that i want to open a modal and take user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you write a separate controller for you modal. That will greatly help you to maintain your code later.

If I understand correctly (from your tags) you use an this one: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
From your main controller, open the modal:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

note the resolve function, you can pass extra parameters like this to modal controller.

In modal controller:

```
angular.module('your.awesomeApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
```

note the third parameter, it will be values, that you have passed.

Comment: do i need to add dependancy or any extra parameter to my existing controller?     'app.controller('InventoryCtrl',['$scope', '$location','$http','ModalService',function($scope, $location, $http,ModalService)'

Comment: No, no extra dependencies for controller is needed, however you will need a dependency for you app: `angular.module('yourModuleName', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ui.bootstrap's](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) components which include a modal. You won't have to use a separate controller.

Answer (score 0):

Look this example:

```
/* Main controller */
App.controller("JustificativaModalController",  function($scope, $modal) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        controller : "ControllerModal",
        templateUrl : "TemplateModal.html",
        resolve: {
            $callback: function () {
                return function(param){
                    /* This function print value(param) dispached in modal controller */
                    console.log(param);
                };
            },
            $send: function(){
                return function(){
                    /* This function send param for the modal */
                    return {param1:"Hello Word Main"};
                };
            }
        }
    });
});

/* Modal controller */
App.controller("JustificativaModalController", function($scope, $modalInstance, $callback, $send) {
    $scope.init = function(){
        /* This function print value(param) dispached in main controller */
        console.log($send);

        /* This send data to main controller */
        $callback({param1:"Hello Word Modal"});
    };
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module devices due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $compileProvider
    at hasOwnPropertyFn `     
I am getting above error when tried above solution. I have app.js which contains routing info. does it has anything to do this modal template routing?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dRahuG?p=preview).  Thanks @Remigijus, @Emir Marques

```
 $scope.open = function (user) {
          $scope.user = user;
          $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              backdrop: true,
              windowClass: 'modal',
              controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                  $scope.user = user;
                  $scope.submit = function () {
                      $log.log('Submiting user info.');
                      $log.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                  }
                  $scope.cancel = function () {
                      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                  };
              },
              resolve: {
                  user: function () {
                      return $scope.user;
                  }
              }
          });
      };
```